# MSSQL - Change DB OWNER to existing user

Tags: sql-server, sql

We have an old DB, 'ourDB', which was originally created by user: **X**

Now user **X** has been deleted and no longer exists on the DB Server.

However the user **X** is STILL the owner of the DB 'ourDB'.

Can we, ***without any risk for running software***, change the DB owner to an existing user called 'newOwner'?

How is this done?

Something like this?:

```
USE ourDB
GO
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'newOwner'
GO
```

I'm a bit worried about changing the db_owner of a db as it seems like a major operation, so if anyone knows of possible consequences it would be very nice to hear :).

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no visible impact from running this on a live system (pretty sure I've done it plenty of times). Be aware that the new owner will be mapped to dbo. As always, if you're unsure, try it on a test system/database first.